# how can i start using docker container using Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am using ubuntu 18.04
I have docker-ce installed
I have a file named Dockerfile
I didn't have any other files
how can I start using this container

Comment: Can u push your dockerfile???

Comment: sorry I cannot do that its client personal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to build an image from Dockerfile. To do this:

1. Go to the directory containing Dockerfile
2. Run (change `<image_name>` to some meaningful name): `docker build -t <image_name> .`

After image is built we can finally run it: `docker run -it <image_name>`
There multiple options how the image can be run so I encourage you to read some docs.